# Как получить доступ к элементу из ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate.DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

У меня есть динамический список:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="CheckBoxList" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding SelectedTicket}" ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Height="24" BorderBrush="#D8D8D8" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

И есть кнопка:

```
 <Button Content="Удалить ответ" Padding="12, 5" Command="{Binding DeleteAnswers}" CommandParameter="{x:Reference Name=CheckBoxList}"/>
```

Эта кнопка должна удалять определённые данные, которые "пометит" `ChechkBox`.

Чтобы она их могла удалить я сделал команду, в которой я **по идее** должен получить список всех этих `CheckBox`'ов. Но я не могу их получить.

**Как их можно получить или передать в команду?**

Comment: У вас же есть привязанная коллекция `ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}"`! Значит в `Answer` должно быт `bool` свойство, кот. привязано к чекбоксу. Далее пробегаете по коллекции `Answers` и находите подлежащие удалению.

Comment: `mvvm` - `получить чекбоксы` - две совершенно несовместимые вещи. Ваша ViewModel не должна знать о том, что у вас находится в View, а значит никаких `x:Name="CheckBoxList"` быть не должно! Аналогично и тут `CommandParameter="{x:Reference Name=CheckBoxList}"` - вы работаете с контролом, а не с данными, это грубое нарушение MVVM.